# Cuantas condiciones puedo agregar en un bucle while

Tags: javascript, while

Me inicio en la programación y acudo a su ayuda.

hice un bucle **while** el cual responde correctamente cuando agrego una condición, sin embargo cuando agrego una 2da condición el bucle entra dentro de un ciclo infinito a pesar de que las condiciones son verdaderas y deba salir del bucle.

Comparto mi código y quedo agradecido con sus prontas respuestas:

```
var operacion= prompt("Ingresu su operación");
while(operacion!="sumar" || operacion!="restar"){           
    operacion= prompt("Esta operación no está contemplada");    
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflowes. Te recomiendo si no lo haz hecho pasarte por [ask].  Podrias especificar tambien cuando deseas que se ejecute el ciclo `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el tipo de condición que estás usando. `||` o también conocido como `OR` checa si alguna de las dos condiciones es cierta o no.

Entonces si analizamos lo que tu código hace:

`while (operacion != "sumar" || operacion != "restar")`

- Checa que la variable `operacion` que recibió como texto desde el prompt sea diferente ya sea de "restar" o de "sumar".
- Si el usuario ingresa "restar" entonces revisa ambas condiciones:
- `operacion != "sumar"`-> se cumple, ya no revisa la otra condición, por lo que continúa dentro del ciclo.
- Si el usuario ingresa "sumar" entonces revisa ambas condiciones:

  - `operacion != "sumar"` no se cumple, revisa la siguiente condición, `operacion != "restar"`, se cumple por lo que continúa dentro del ciclo.

Como puedes ver ambas condiciones nunca se cumplirán, porque ese es parte de la condición `||` o una o la otra pero no ambas. Si entiendo lo que quieres hacer debes cambiar tu condición a un `AND` también conocido como `&&`

```js
var operacion= prompt("Ingresu su operación");

while(operacion!="sumar" && operacion != "restar"){
    operacion= prompt("Esta operación no está contemplada"); 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, me quedó claro su explicación.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre va a ser true ese bucle porque estas diciendo que "operacion" sea distinta de "sumar" o distinta de "restar", tienes que cambiar el OR "||" por un AND "&&"